# react-intl: change div direction based on current locale

Tags: reactjs, localization, react-intl

So, here is my `App` component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("en");

  return (
    <IntlProvider
      locale={lang}
      key={lang}
      messages={lang == "en" ? englishMessages : arabicMessages}
    >
      <AppBar>
        <LangSwitch
          checked={lang == "en"}
          onChange={() => setLang(lang == "en" ? "ar" : "en")}
        ></LangSwitch>
      </AppBar>
      <Game />
    </IntlProvider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and, this is my `Game` component:

```
const Game = ()=>
   (<div direction = "???">
     I want to set direction to ltr if current locale is 'en' other wise to 'rtl'
   </div>)
```

How can I read the current value of `locale`-set in the parent component of `IntlProvider`- inside child component of `Game` and set the property `direction` accordingly?

Comment: Hi Hans, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass state `lang` to your `Game` component,

```
<Game lang={lang}/>
```

And your `Game` component should be,

```
const Game = (props)=> ( //provide props argument here
   <div direction ={props.lang === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}>  //check your condition
     I want to set direction to ltr if current locale is 'en' other wise to 'rtl'
   </div>
)
```

---

**Update**

Another way is wrapping your component with `injectIntl` HOC.

```
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl';

const Game = ({intl})=> {
  console.log(intl.locale)
  return ( 
   <div direction ={intl.locale === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'}>  //check your condition
     I want to set direction to ltr if current locale is 'en' other wise to 'rtl'
   </div>
  )
}

export default injectIntl(Game)
```

Comment: It works, but isn't there any better way than prop-drilling?